# Angularjs работа с ckeckbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Имеем checkbox для создания редактирования новости на php нужно выделить все поля из базы как они были заполнены, выделяю их к примеру в checkbox, а именно ставлю галочку на Азербайджан потом ищу в поиске Австралия убираю галочку, далее очищаю строку поиска и на Азербайджане не стоит галочке(а именно приминились параметры со скрипта), как выделить самому галочки, но чтобы ни чего не возвращалось к первоначальному состоянию. Вот пример:

```js
        var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.country = [
                    { 'name': 'Австрия', 'desc': 'Австрия', 'check': 'true' },
                    { 'name': 'Азербайджан', 'desc': 'Азербайджан',  'check': 'false'  },
                    { 'name': 'Албания', 'desc': 'Албания',  'check': 'true'  }
                    ];
});
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <input ng-model="query">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in country | filter:query">
      <label>
        <input name="country[]" type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected"  ng-checked="{{item.check}}" value="{{item.desc}}" >{{item.desc}}</label>
          
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
        var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.country = [
                    { 'name': 'Австрия', 'desc': 'Австрия', 'check': true },
                    { 'name': 'Азербайджан', 'desc': 'Азербайджан',  'check': false  },
                    { 'name': 'Албания', 'desc': 'Албания',  'check': true  }
                    ];
});
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <input ng-model="query">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in country | filter:query">
      <label>
        {{item.check}}<input name="country" type="checkbox" ng-model="item.check"  ng-checked="{{item.check}}" value="{{item.desc}}" >{{item.desc}}</label>
          
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Измените ng-model="item.check"

Comment: мой косяк. Да сам понял уже поставил в ответ Спасибо)

Comment: А зачем `ng-checked`?

Comment: да получается ng-checked не нужен, так как в модели сразу указаны те которые чекнуты